# Can not connet to mongodb database in nextjs

Tags: mongodb, next.js

environment

- nodejs: v18.17.0
- nextjs: v13.4.13
- mongodb version: MongoDB 6.0.8 Community
- mongodb-tool: mongodbcompass
- operation system: windows 10

---

details:

- use nextjs as my application backend server
- write api in nextjs, api path / file path: src/pages/api/v1/knowledge
- frontend request url(http://localhost:3000/api/v1/knowledge) timeout

---

my guess:

- nextjs works
- mongodb can not connect, but I can not figure out why it not working as my expect. I might write the wrong code.

---

src/pages/api/v1/knowledge below:

```js
import { MongoClient, Db } from "mongodb";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const resolveGetRequest = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
  db: Db
) => {
  const collection = db.collection("KnowledgePointComments");
  const data = await collection.find({}).toArray();
  res.status(200).json({
    code: "0",
    messgae: "success",
    data: "hello-world!",
  });
};

const resolvePostRequest = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
  db: Db
) => {};

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
  const dbName = "TEST_FRONTEND_EVERYDAY";
  const client = new MongoClient(url);
  // console.log(client);
  try {
    const __res = await client.connect();
    console.log("@", __res);
    console.log("connect mongodb success!");

    const db: Db = client.db(dbName);

    // 获取随机知识点
    if (req.method === "GET") {
      resolveGetRequest(req, res, db);
    }

    // 发布知识点
    if (req.method === "POST") {
      resolvePostRequest(req, res, db);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      code: "-1",
      message: "unable to connect mongodb",
    });
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

- edit mongod.cfg，change bandi from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0
- restart mongodb